# Создание многострочного EditText с линиями

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как создать EditText(необязательно) , что бы он был на весь экран и с такими линиями?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. При использовании кода в  ответе  Likhanov'a получается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код немного изменён:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.x.myfirstnormal.ActivityAdd"
    android:background="#D6E100">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="Name*"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="552dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="168dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="552dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="Clear all"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Female"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/female" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:text="Female*"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" />

    <!--<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="147dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="228dp">
-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.example.x.myfirstnormal.LinedEditText
            android:id="@+id/mainEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--</ScrollView>-->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @pavlofff Изменил вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="8" <!-- приоритетное кол-во линий для отображения -->
    android:minLines="6" <!-- минимум линий -->
    android:gravity="top|left" <!-- позиция курсора -->
    android:maxLines="10" <!-- максимум линий -->
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
/>
```

Если нужны линии в `EditText` то необходимо создать свой кастомный `EditText`
Пример.

Создаете класс

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {

    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
      //  mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor()); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //int count = getLineCount();

        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;

        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

И такой xml файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/multiline_exdittext_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.LinedEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edittxt_multilines"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Пример того, что получилось

[image: Пример того, что получилось]
[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233683/9007098)

Comment: А как такие же линии сделать знаете?

Comment: а там какие получились? Такие же в плане стиля?

Comment: получилось текстовое поле , без линий , просто текстовое поле.

Comment: похоже это возможно только созданием своего кастомного editText

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное ! Не могли бы вы "оптимизировать" код для android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout? У меня после 3 линий идёт пробел между последующими и так между каждыми 3 линиями.

Comment: Проверил на LinearLayout , таже  проблема что и с  android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @True-hacker к сожалению не знаю почему у вас так. Я прикрепил к ответу свой скрин

Comment: Я тоже прикрепил .